# Why can't I push a vector of integers to a 2-D vector of integers in C++?

Tags: c++, integer, push-back, 2d-vector

Here is my 2D vector of integers.

```
vector<vector<int>> nodes (r*c, vector<int> (5));
```

using a for loop I am trying to push_back values in this vector. r and c are passed integers to this function.

```
for(i = 0; i < r*c; i++)

{        
       nodes[i].push_back({i/c, i%c, -1, -1, 0});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nodes[i]` is a vector of *integers*. You're trying to append a *vector* to a vector of integers.

Either do:

```
nodes.push_back({i/c, i%c, -1, -1, 0});
```

or

```
nodes[i] = {i/c, i%c, -1, -1, 0};
```

The second solution being the best since you already gave the proper dimension to your vector. No need to add `r*c` more elements...

in your code, either create empty, and populate with `push_back`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> nodes;
for(i = 0; i < r*c; i++)
{        
   nodes.push_back({i/c, i%c, -1, -1, 0});
}
```

or create with proper dimension and assign items:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> nodes (r*c, std::vector<int> (5));
for(i = 0; i < r*c; i++)
{        
   nodes[i] = {i/c, i%c, -1, -1, 0};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use method `insert` instead of `push_back`

```
nodes[i].insert( nodes[I].end(), {i/c, i%c, -1, -1, 0});
```

But before this you should declare the vector like

```
vector<vector<int>> nodes (r*c );
```

Otherwise first 5 elements of each subvector will contain zeroes.

Also you can use method `assign`

```
nodes[i].assign(  {i/c, i%c, -1, -1, 0});
```

Comment: that's not the problem. `nodes[i]` is a vector of _integers_. You cannot insert a vector in it. That's why `push_back` fails (and `insert` compiles but god knows what it does. Segfault here)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Нщг You are wrong. It is not a vector that is inserted . It is values of the initializer list that are inserted.

Comment: I still have a doubt, and you obviously did not test that because that `nodes[i].insert( nodes[I].end(), {i/c, i%c, -1, -1, 0});` does not compile (`I` is undeclared). Also `nodes.insert( nodes.end(), {i/c, i%c, -1, -1, 0});` compiles!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I do not know what you compiled. It is a valid code. Maybe your old compiler does not support C++ 11.

Comment: `I` is uppercase. It is _not_ valid code. And my compiler supports C++11, and your code compiles (after fixing the `I` stuff) but doesn't work. Try printing `nodes[0][2]` after your insertion you'll get `0`. I get `-1` as expected.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre One again I do not know what you are compiling. This program is valid  #include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
 std::vector<std::vector<int>> v( 1 );
 
 v[0].insert( v[0].end(), { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } );

 for ( int x : v[0] ) std::cout << x << ' ';
 std::cout << std::endl;
 
 return 0;
}